# SQL query to get column names if it has specific value

Tags: sql

I have a situation here, I have a table with a flag assigned to the column names(like 'Y' or 'N'). I have to select the column names of a row, if it have a specific value.

My Table:

```
Name|sub-1|sub-2|sub-3|sub-4|sub-5|sub-6|
-----------------------------------------
Tom | Y   |     | Y   | Y   |     | Y   |
Jim | Y   |  Y  |     |     | Y   | Y   |
Ram |     |  Y  |     | Y   | Y   |     |
```

So I need to get, what are all the subs are have 'Y' flag for a particular Name. 
For Example:

If I select

```
Tom
```

I need to get the list of 'Y' column name in query output.

```
Subs
____
sub-1
sub-3
sub-4
sub-6
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: try this select Column_name 
from Information_schema.columns 
where Table_name like 'table name'

Comment: Your database needs a fix.  Where you have columns you need rows.

Comment: we cannot have those rows as column, because the Name will be created on daily basis.

Comment: @ Darji Jigar - I tried it did not work, Can you give me a query for the same?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Below code works for me.

```
select t.Subs from (select name, u.subs,u.val
from TableName s
unpivot
(
  val
  for subs  in (sub-1, sub-2, sub-3,sub-4,sub-5,sub-6,sub-7)
) u where u.val='Y') T
where t.name='Tom'
```

Comment: Consider improving your answer. _[Code-only answers may fall under 'Very Low Quality' ...and are candidates for deletion....We've always touted that we aren't a code factory. We are the people who teach others to fish. Code-only answers only feed a person for a day](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques)_

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your database model is not normalized. If it was properly normalized the query would be easy. So the workaround is to normalize the model "on-the-fly" to be able to make the query:

```
select col_name
from (
   select name, sub_1 as val, 'sub_1' as col_name
   from the_table
   union all
   select name, sub_2, 'sub_2'
   from the_table
   union all
   select name, sub_3, 'sub_3'
   from the_table
   union all
   select name, sub_4, 'sub_4'
   from the_table
   union all
   select name, sub_5, 'sub_5'
   from the_table
   union all
   select name, sub_6, 'sub_6'
   from the_table
) t
where name = 'Tom'
and val = 'Y'
```

The above is standard SQL and should work on any (relational) DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I am near to the solution. I can get for all rows. (I just used 2 columns)

```
select col from ( select col, case s.col when 'sub-1' then sub-1 when 'sub-2' then sub-2 end AS val from mytable cross join ( select 'sub-1' AS col union all select 'sub-2' ) s ) s where val ='Y'
```

It gives the columns for all row. I need the same data for a single row. Like if I select "Tom", I need the column names for 'Y' value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this under a few assumptions here. The first is that you KNOW the names of the columns of the table in question. Second, that this is SQL Server. Oracle and MySql have ways of performing this, but I don't know the syntax for that.

Anyways, what I'd do is perform an 'UNPIVOT' on the data.

There's a lot of parans there, so to explain.  The actual 'unpivot' statement (aliased as UNPVT) takes the data and twists the columns into rows, and the SELECT associated with it provides the data that is being returned. Here's I used the 'Name', and placed the column names under the 'Subs' column and the corresponding value into the 'Val' column. To be precise, I'm talking about this aspect of the above code:

```
SELECT [Name], [Subs], [Val]
   FROM 
      (SELECT [Name], [Sub-1], [Sub-2], [Sub-3], [Sub-4], [Sub-5], [Sub-6]
          FROM pvt) p
   UNPIVOT
      (Orders FOR [Name] IN 
           ([Name], [Sub-1], [Sub-2], [Sub-3], [Sub-4], [Sub-5], [Sub-6])
   )AS unpvt
```

My next step was to make that a 'sub-select' where I could find the specific name and val that was being hunted for.  That would leave you with a SQL Statement that looks something along these lines

```
SELECT [Name], [Subs], [Val]
   FROM (
      SELECT [Name], [Subs], [Val]
      FROM 
        (SELECT [Name], [Sub-1], [Sub-2], [Sub-3], [Sub-4], [Sub-5], [Sub-6]
          FROM pvt) p
      UNPIVOT
         (Orders FOR [Name] IN 
              ([Name], [Sub-1], [Sub-2], [Sub-3], [Sub-4], [Sub-5], [Sub-6])
         )AS unpvt 
) AS pp 
WHERE 1 = 1 
   AND pp.[Val] = 'Y'
   AND pp.[Name] = 'Tom'
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select col from (
   select col,
       case s.col
         when 'sub-1' then sub-1
         when 'sub-2' then sub-2
         when 'sub-3' then sub-3
         when 'sub-4' then sub-4
         when 'sub-5' then sub-5
         when 'sub-6' then sub-6
       end AS val
   from mytable
   cross join
   (
    select 'sub-1' AS col union all
    select 'sub-2' union all
    select 'sub-3' union all
    select 'sub-4' union all
    select 'sub-5' union all
    select 'sub-6'

   ) s on name="Tom"
) s
where val ='Y'
```

included the join condition as

on name="Tom"

Comment: Your specific problem/question is rather unclear. Please use complete English sentences containing all usual elements (Subject, Predecate, Object) and you may get an answer :-)